# dplyr r turn first line-item text KPI to NA by dimension

Tags: r, if-statement, dplyr, group-by

Here is the dataframe `starwars` from the `dplyr` library in R. What I'm trying to do is turn the first line item of `mean_height` and `median_height` of the group by to NA.

So for example, if you ran the code snippet below, I'd want `mean_height` = NA and `median_height` at the line item of `hair_color` = auburn and `skin_color` = fair. After that particular group_by, `mean_height` = NA and `median_height` at the line item of `hair_color` = black and `skin_color` = blue, grey, and so on!

I'd prefer the solution in dplyr

Thanks so much for the help!

```
library(dplyr)

dimensions_groupBy <- c("hair_color", "skin_color")
measures_choices <- c("height", "mass")
aggregating_choices <- list("mean" = mean, "median" = median)

starwars %>% 
  group_by(across(all_of(dimensions_groupBy))) %>% 
  summarise(across(all_of(measures_choices),
                   aggregating_choices,
                   .names = "{fn}_{col}"))
```

Comment: What is the issue with athat code

Comment: there is no issue with the code. just can't figure out a way to add the specified condition. The code itself first hand should just produce a dataframe to which I'd like the particular question I asked applied to it.

Comment: `summarise` returns a single row per group

Comment: Can you check the solution below.  Do you want the expected output as that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we want to have a `NA` row on each group by

```
library(dplyr)
starwars %>% 
   group_by(across(all_of(dimensions_groupBy))) %>% 
   summarise(across(all_of(measures_choices),
                  list(mean = ~ c(NA, mean(.)), median = ~ c(NA, median(.))),
                 .names = "{fn}_{col}"), .groups = 'drop')
```